# Is it possible to return an address with Direct Request V2 Job Specs?

Tags: chainlink

Is it possible to return an `address` with Chainlink Direct Request V2 Job Specs?

I've noticed an ETH `address` is around 42 bytes so it won't fit into a `bytes32` response type.  I see the listed "[Response Types](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/#response-types)" in the docs list:

- `uint256`
- `int256`
- `bool`
- `bytes32` / `bytes`

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to return a `bytes32` and then convert it to an address.

From the [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html):

> If you convert a type that uses a larger byte size to an address, for example bytes32, then the address is truncated. To reduce conversion ambiguity version 0.4.24 and higher of the compiler force you make the truncation explicit in the conversion. Take for example the 32-byte value `0x111122223333444455556666777788889999AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFCCCC`.

> You can use `address(uint160(bytes20(b)))`, which results in `0x111122223333444455556666777788889999aAaa`, or you can use `address(uint160(uint256(b)))`, which results in `0x777788889999AaAAbBbbCcccddDdeeeEfFFfCcCc`.

[Also see this related question.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50914/convert-bytes32-to-address)